# Submit button not working within form and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a problem with the submit button: it just won't work. It seems to work fine with my previous forms. I'm using the Spry Validation as well. It's a simple HTML  with a PHP. I can't see where is my mistake (and I'm just starting to learn PHP). I've looked around the forum already and on the internet, but I couldn't find an answer for my problem. I'm trying to get a basic form e-mailed to me with an option to upload a file within the same form. Does the problem come from the form formatting or the PHP file? Here are the codes I have:
This is the HTML form located within a `<body><div id="content">...</div></body>`

```
<p><form action="upload.php" name="form1" id="form1" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset><legend><em>Please fill this form</em></legend>

First Name: <span id="sprytextfield1">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required="required" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Please enter your first name.</span></span><br/><br/>
Last Name: <span id="sprytextfield2">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Please enter your last name.</span></span><br/><br/>
Job Title: <span id="sprytextfield3">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Please enter your desired title.</span></span><br/><br/>
Address: <span id="sprytextfield4">
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Please enter your address.</span></span><br/><br/>
Postal Code: <span id="sprytextfield5">
<input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">(i.e.: A0A 0A0)</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg"></span></span><br/>
<br/>
City: <span id="sprytextfield6">
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Please enter the name of your city.</span></span><br/><br/>
Province: <span id="spryselect1">
<select name="province" id="province">
  <option value="ontario">Ontario</option>
  <option value="quebec">Quebec</option>
  <option value="britishcolumbia">British Columbia</option>
  <option value="alberta">Alberta</option>
  <option value="manitoba">Manitoba</option>
  <option value="saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
</select>
</span><br/><br/>
Phone Number: <span id="sprytextfield7">
<input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" maxlength="13" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">(i.e.: XXX-XXX-XXXX)</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">(i.e.: XXX-XXX-XXXX)</span></span><br/>
<br/>
<hr />

Additional information:<br />
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<label for="file">Resume/CV (PDF or Word format only):</label>
<input type="hidden" name="max" value="100000"/>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/><br><br />
E-mail: 
<span id="sprytextfield8">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your e-mail address is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">(i.e.: aaa@aaaa.com)</span></span><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" />
</fieldset>
</form></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the external PHP (upload.php) file located with the same bracket type of bracket as the previous HTML(same CSS and HTML body):

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "aaplication/doc"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }


$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$postal=$_POST['postal'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$province=$_POST['province'];


$date=gmdate("M d Y");


print"<p><b>$date</b></p>";
print"<p>Thank you $firstname $lastname! We will get back to you.</p>";


$to="someuser@gmail.com";

$subject="Candidate Resume";

$body="Date:$date \n Subject:$subject \n First Name:$firstname \n Last Name:$lastname \n Title:$title \n Address:$address \n City:$city \n Province:$province \n Postal Code:$postal \n Telephone:$phone \n Email:$email \n Additional Information:$comments \n\n";

mail($to,$subject,$body);

?>
```

Comment: when you say it wont work what do you mean? the form isnt submiting when you click the button? Or you arent getting the data you expect in the php file or what?

Comment: I'd recommend you learn how to troubleshoot. Figure out what is working. If you put `die('yo');` at the top of your php, does it die and echo yo? Then your problem is in the php. If not, then your problem is in the html. There, you just split the area in which your problem could be in half. If it doesn't echo, does your html connect to php if you create 'test.php' and use that to `echo 'test'`? Learning to solve your own problems is a very important programming skill.

Comment: You seem to be using the "required" attribute wrong, though that probably isn't your problem. It should just be `required` where you have `required='required'`

Comment: @JamesG. Either is acceptable for required. Kyttee if your problem is you dont get the email its probably because you are outputting content before you sent the email. Move the print statements to after your email statements

Comment: By not working, I meant that I'm pressing submit button and nothing happens. The PHP doesn't even load.

Comment: Thank you for the "required" ans troubleshoot trick. I've just been taught for this attribute that I should write it require="required"; a  HTML5 rule that I didn't double check...

I'll try the debug and let you know how it worked.

Comment: So I've used the die('yo'); as well as the test.php and none of them were responsive; which by @JamesG. means that the problem is in by HTML. I've already tried debugging it and I couldn't see where the mistake was; all my content are located within their div tags and everything seems proper. No syntax error as far as I can tell; all the tags are closed...I'm really pulling my hair on this one. It's not the first form I create, but this one just doesn't seem to work properly. Could it be something with the Spry Validation that is interfering?

Comment: I'd delete everything other than the form tags, and if they still aren't working, then compare them to working ones. I'll look into this :)

Comment: Using the exact html that you posted, I got upload.php to echo yo.

Comment: Typing in "dfas," into first name(and nothing else), using your EXACT code, It printed:

Invalid file
Oct 19 2013

Thank you dfas ! We will get back to you.

Comment: You have your file size set way too low. On my website I have 197654 set as the max pdf upload size, and I only use pdf uploads for legal forms that I know the contents of. I don't know what other problems you might be having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script works, just increase the filesize value in the if statement to something the will accommodate these types of files.
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 500000)

Your were only allowing for 19k.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP error log on your server to see if you can get some information on why its failing. That has helped me numerous times when debugging some code that wasn't working.